# Altium assign one pin to multiple pads?

Tags: altium

I am using a P Mosfet in the schematic, pin 1, 2, 5, 6 are all connected together. How is this done in altium?

[image]

Comment: IIRC, if you overlay the pins on the schematic (really done in the library editor when creating the symbol), Altium will automatically put in a junction to electrically connect the pins together when you run a wire to that location.  If it works you should see a junction dot appear.

Comment: Personally, I just put 4 pins on the schematic symbol. It's a bit messy, but it makes sure your layout guy knows exactly what you want.

Comment: I agree with @ThePhoton. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest (and probably the most common) way of doing this is placing multiple pins on top of one another in the schematic. If you ensure all of the electrical "hotspots" are lined up with one another on the grid, they will automatically be "read" as connected to each other. Then, if you want to show all of the pin numbers (like what is shown in your image) you can adjust the pin number margins to separate them from one another. For example Pin 1 will have a margin of 10 DXP units, Pin 2 will have a margin of 20 DXP units, Pin 3 will have a margin of 30 DXP units, and Pin 4 will have a margin of 40 DXP units. They will show up in the schematic just like your image.

Answer (score 12):

This is now possible in Altium 21; this YouTube video shows how https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qe4ZQYSb2DI

Basically you can open the component in the Schematic Library Editor, "Edit" the linked Footprint Model, and click the new "Pin Map" button on the top line next to the name. Then enter a comma-separated list of pad numbers that should be assigned to the one symbol pin (i.e. "1, 2, 5, 6" on symbol pin 1).

Comment: actually this should be the best answer it helped alot since altium documentation about this is very bad. I took me 2 hours to figure to get to this option . thank u

Answer (score 5):

This is long-requested feature, it has a history on Altium's bug/feature tracker that goes back to 2011.  It is currently listed as 'in development'.  If you have an Altium Live account you can view the feature request here: https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Bug/317

Another workaround is to assign the same identifier to multiple pads in the PCB footprint, which will cause them all to be connected to the corresponding schematic pin.  However this requires customizing the footprint to suit the pin layout of the component.  This is not such a big deal in things like SO8 MOSFETS which have a conventional pinout, but would be a pain for ICs that use ganged pins but an otherwise standard package.

Comment: Changing the footprint pins designator to all the same pin is very common for Altium. It only requires that you create a separate footprint for that part. A good way of doing this is using a label designator. Altium recognizes phrases as well so you could say "drain" on the pin designator and also on the footprint pad designators.

Comment: As of 2018, it's unbelievable that the "industry standard" software lacks such a commonly needed feature.

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't gotten a better answer, I'll say you should just add multiple pins to your symbol. It's not as compact as overlapping the pins, but it makes your design intent, and the required connections, crystal clear.

It can look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the same identifier to multiple pads in the PCB footprint you also can assign the same JumperID to pads that connected together. But as you can see this is almost the same because for each type of pattern with connected pins you must have separate copy of "pad record" in library.
In the early days of Altium Designer there was another option. Every schematic library element can have pin map for each connected model. As footprint is a model you can have a mapping table. Mapping was designed not only one to one, but also one to list. I mean one pin from schematic library's element to list of pins from pattern. (https://designspark.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000098289-Multiple-PCB-Pin-for-a-single-Schematic-Pin). This feature was slightly more powerful then dumb patterns with connected pins as this mapping table is not the part of pattern. But still twice messy: this table must not be the part of logic element (i.e. element of schematic library) instead it must be the part of component; pin numbers seeng on shematics never show mapped pattern's pin numbers, so nobody know did you done any remap or don't.
  For now this type of logic-pattern connections is not supported by Altium though mapping tables for each shematic library element still presents.
So, of cource, AD cannot be "industry standard" at list at component's library design.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked now, during symbol creation, you can now put comma delimited designation numbers and it will auto link to relevant pins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are images to visualize the existing answers.

## Schematic–footprint pin mappings

You can access the mappings between schematic pins and footprint pins this way.

[image: Schematic–footprint pin mappings]

## Commas in schematic pin designators

Or you can just simply use commas in schematic pin designators. You don’t have to modify the pin map by yourself, as this does the same.

[image: Using commas in schematic pin designators]